# Jogo da Velha - Implementar lógica

Tags: java

Bom pessoal, meu trabalho final do semestre é montar um jogo da velha em java, fiz todo o visual dele, mas o problema vem ai: Preciso fazer com que a cada clique do mouse ele altere o ícone dos botões (primeiro clique um X, segundo clique um O), e que quando se repetir na horizontal, vertical ou diagonal, uma JOptionPane apareça com a mensagem "você venceu" ou o nome do vencedor, coisa do tipo... como fazer essas ações ? Não estou conseguindo, alguém poderia ajudar ? Eis o código:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Jogo extends JFrame{
    private JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9;
    private JLabel l1;
    private Dimension dim;
    private Font f;

        public Jogo(){
            dim = new Dimension (90,90);
            setTitle("Jogo da Velha");
            setBounds(300,160,400,450);
            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setBackground(new Color (197,197,197));
            setLayout(null);

            f = new Font("Tahoma",Font.ITALIC,17);
            setFont(f);

            JMenuBar mbar = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu opcoes = new JMenu("Opções");
            JMenu sair = new JMenu("Sair");

            JMenuItem sMim = new JMenuItem("Sobre mim");
            JMenuItem sprogram = new JMenuItem("Sobre o Programa");

            opcoes.add(sMim);
            opcoes.add(sprogram);

            mbar.add(opcoes);
            mbar.add(sair);

            setJMenuBar(mbar);

            l1 = new JLabel();
            l1.setText("Gabriel Ozzy Santos");
            l1.setBounds(130,10,200,30);
            l1.setFont(f);
            this.add(l1);

                b1 = new JButton();
                b1.setSize(dim);
                b1.setLocation(30,50);
                this.add(b1);

                b2 = new JButton();
                b2.setSize(dim);
                b2.setLocation(150,50);
                this.add(b2);

                b3 = new JButton();
                b3.setSize(dim);
                b3.setLocation(270,50);
                this.add(b3);

                b4 = new JButton();
                b4.setSize(dim);
                b4.setLocation(30,170);
                this.add(b4);

                b5 = new JButton();
                b5.setSize(dim);
                b5.setLocation(150,170);
                this.add(b5);

                b6 = new JButton();
                b6.setSize(dim);
                b6.setLocation(270,170);
                this.add(b6);

                b7 = new JButton();
                b7.setSize(dim);
                b7.setLocation(30,290);
                this.add(b7);

                b8 = new JButton();
                b8.setSize(dim);
                b8.setLocation(150,290);
                this.add(b8);

                b9 = new JButton();
                b9.setSize(dim);
                b9.setLocation(270,290);
                this.add(b9);
        }
        public static void main (String [] args){
            new Jogo().setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

já qué é um trabalho de escola, não existe momento mais oportuno para aprender.

Algumas sugestões em relação a seu código:

**1. Separação de Reponsabilidades**

Notei que ainda não existe lógica de negócio no seu código, o que é um bom sinal. Entendo que há uma vontade natural em colocar o código do negócio misturado com a visão, mas evite isso a todo custo.

Em outras palavras, você deve montar a lógica do jogo da velha fora da classe Jogo. Monte uma classe que se chama JogoDaVelha e nela inclua os atributos e métodos necessários para que um jogo da velha aconteça do início ao fim. Depois de ter a classe pronta e testada, aí sim você vai se preocupar com a visão.

Separar a visão do negócio é algo de suma importância. Basicamente, pode-se dizer que é um dos pilares que sustentam os softwares realmente grandes que são feitos hoje em dia. Dentro desse contexto, estude o padrão MVC (Modelo-Controlador-Visão), pois é algo pensado exatamente para separar essas responsabilidades.

Pense sempre em responsabilidades. Qual é o papel da sua classe JogoDaVelha? Você concorda que essa classe deve simplesmente controlar a instância de um determinado jogo? Em outras palavras, essa classe não quer saber se o jogo é jogado pela Web, pelo Desktop ou, até mesmo, pelo Console. Não importa pra ela. Na verdade, ela não está nem "sabendo" de onde ela está sendo jogada.

**2.  Visão**

Não vou entrar no mérito do controlador aqui, vamos direto pra visão para ficar mais fácil de você compreender como tudo se conecta.

Na classe Jogo acima, um dos atributos será do tipo da sua classe JogoDaVelha. Você deverá instanciar esse objeto e trabalhar com ele em cada evento gerado pelos seus botões. Trabalhar com ele significa fazer chamadas aos métodos e mudar o seu estado (mudar o valor dos atributos), na medida em que o jogo acontece.

Para que você faça alguma ação quando o usuário clicar em um botão, você deve implementar um ActionListener. Basicamente, é a forma mais comum de fazer um tratador de eventos. É um evento, pois é disparado por uma entidade extena, no caso, o seu usuário clicará no botão e isso gerará um evento.

Exemplo:

```
b1 = new JButton();
b1.setSize(dim);
b1.setLocation(30,50);
this.add(b1);
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       System.out.println("You clicked the button");
    });
```

O código acima, embora verboso, não é complicado de compreender. O que está sendo feito é a inclusão de um ActionListener na lista de ActionListeners do botão b1. Assim, quando o botão for clicado, ele notificará os objetos que estão nesta lista, chamando, para cada um, o método actionPerformed.

Veja um exemplo com dois ActionListeners:

```
    b1 = new JButton();
    b1.setSize(dim);
    b1.setLocation(30,50);
    this.add(b1);
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("OI");
        }
    });

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("OI2");
        }
    });
```

Assim, quando você clicar, os dois actionPerformed acima serão executados.

Repare que os objetos do tipo ActionListener criados são anônimos. Anonimos, pois o objeto não tem uma variável da qual você possa referenciá-lo no "mundo de fora".

No caso acima, estamos apenas imprimindo no console uma mensagem. Para o jogo da velha, a ideia é fazer duas coisas: Mudar o estado do seu jogo da velha e checar se o jogo terminou. Mudar o estado significa marcar na estrutura de dados interna do jogo que certa célula foi marcada com X ou O.

Claro que no momento de implementar dificuldades aparecerão e você pode tomar um outro caminho, mas a ideia de separar as responsabilidades deve ser sempre a sua maior preocupação.

Comment: Certo, consegui compreender porém tive duas dificuldades !Para criar a outra classe, Conheço a lógica do Jogo da Velha perfeitamente, porém, não consigo de forma alguma fazer com que o jogo entenda que, se por exemplo o "X" se repetir 3 vezes na horizontal ou diagonal, acaba o jogo... E também não consigo fazer com que a cada clique, os botões exerçam uma actionlistener diferentes(um clique do jogador X, e outro do jogador O).

Comment: @Gabriel, você já criou a estrutura de dados para armazenar os valores marcados? Uma matriz[3][3] seria a estrutura mais básica. Você poderia, inclusive, fazer uma matriz de String que começaria com as posições nulas e poderia receber X ou O. Feito isso, você faz algoritmos que percorrem essa matriz verificando se em alguma linha, coluna ou diagonal existem 3 X ou 3 O. Mas como todo problema em computação, existem muitas formas de resolver. Essa é a que acho que vc pode desenvolver mais rapidamente.

Comment: Já enfrentei esse "problema" também :) O que acabei fazendo é como o @cantoni fez -- isto é, criar uma matriz (um 'multi-dimentional array'). O detalhe, é que em vez de X ou O, cada membro do array valia certos pontos. Aí quando X cliquou no canto esqueiro de cima, por exemplo, ganhava pontos. Fiz de um jeito que, ao final, sumava os pontos e daí sabia quem ganhou.

Comment: Acaba sendo que fiz uma solução com matemática, mas há várias outras soluções.

Answer (score 1):

Sobre o botão: No Evento do clique você verifica o texto. Se o texto for "" defina-o "X", se for "X" defina-o para "O", se for "O" defina-o para "".
Vários `if` ou um `switch` resolve isso.

Sobre a vitória: A cada jogada terminada você verifica todos os botões, verificando seu conteúdo e vendo se cada uma das possibilidades de vitória é atendida. E então exibe a mensagem.
Para isto, você pode verificar no texto do botão ou usar variáveis que também são definidas no *backend* para controlar esses dados.